# laravel/elequent - models and relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I trying to learn laravel and to do some tests/demo apps. I've struggling now with laravel/eloquent tables relations. And I need advice.

I have 3 models [Application, Term, AppState] and their tables **applications**[id, terms_id, appStates_id, and other cols ], **terms**[id, startDate, endDate, ...], **app_states**[id, caption]

**Application.php**

```
    public function term()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Term');
    }
    public function appState()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AppState');
    }
```

in  **Term.php** and **AppState.php** i have:

```
    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Application');
    }
```

How I can get let's say "caption"/"startDay"+"endDate" in blade for each application? I can get their ids `$app->terms_id`/`$app->appStates_id` in foreach loop, but i want get `caption` value from `app_states` table.

Has to be this relations also specified in migrations? In some tuts is mentioned, that is not needed in case i want to handle it only in laravel.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a model's relationship values by calling the relationship method like a property.

```php
$application = Application::find(1);

$application->term->startDate;
$application->term->endDate;
$application->appState->caption;
```

Also your relationship with `AppState` is wrong, since your foreign key doesn't follow a `snake_case` typing, you'll need to provide the appropriate key for it

```php
public function appState()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AppState', 'appStates_id');
}
```

You might also want to check `terms_id` as well since the model name (`Term`) is singular but the foreign key is plural.

> Has to be this relations also specified in migrations? In some tuts is mentioned, that is not needed in case i want to handle it only in laravel.

Well, yes, you don't need to if Laravel will only be the one accessing that database. But if any cases in the near future you decide to migrate to a different framework or use the same database in another application, it's better to include these relationships in the migration. Also a database administrator would probably cringe if you don't.

Comment: thanks for reply... I tried this before, but not work -> i got " Trying to get property 'caption' of non-object" error.

Comment: oh, your foreign key for the appStates() relationship is a bit off.. i updated my answer

Comment: thank you, it works...  i think i'll rename a few columns ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

So provided your relationships are correctly setup, you can access them anywhere you have an instance of that model.

So for example, lets say you have passed a collection of applications to your view (`$apps`):

```
@foreach($apps as $app)
    {{ $app->term->startDate }}
    {{ $app->term->endDate }}

    {{ $app->appState->caption }}
@endforeach
```

---

Important Note: We are accessing the Eloquent relationship using `->appState` rather than `->appState()`. The later is actually accessing a Query Builder instance and has some more advanced use cases